# Excluding specific properties when serialising back to XML from data loaded in via XSD.exe generated classes?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties, xsd

I have generated classes from XSD using the "XSD.exe /c" command line. Partial classes were generated, so I "completed" them by adding classes with the same name, which allowed me to add additional properties. However, the value of these properties are being included whenever I serialise data back into XML files. Does anyone know how to prevent this, perhaps via an attribute?

Thanks very much,

Nick Hill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string Foo {get;set;}
```

actually (for completeness only), you can *also* do this by two other name-based patterns - you just wouldn't in this scenario - they are designed for *conditionally* including data during serialization, and (in the second example) disambiguating between "explicitly deserialized to the default" vs "not in the deserialization source":

```
public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() {return false;}
```

or

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool FooSpecified { get { return false;} set {} }
```

Comment: The `ShouldSerializeFoo()` method is especially nice as it can be put in a different file (continuation of the autogenerated partial class). This is the only way I have found to (conditionally) exclude properties in serialization. Works well together with `nillable="true"` on xs:element in the xsd file.